# My 2004 Chevy impala is overheating how can you help me?

Tags: radiator, cooling, water-pump, thermostat

My Chevy impala 2004 I love and is a good car when I drive my car it overheats till I cut on the AC and it would go in the middle again I'm trying to figure out what it is before I spend more money on the car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like the primary cooling fan isn't running. The A/C utilizes a secondary fan, which turns on when you turn your A/C on. The problem could be one of several things.

- The relay going to the primary fan could be bad. It should be the same exact relay as the secondary. If you swap them out, it might tell you if the relay is bad. You can also pull the relay and put a jumper wire directly into the socket, which would power the fan and tell you if it is okay.
- It could be the fan is bad. Doing the above with the jumper would tell you if it's working or not. You could also pull the power wires directly at the fan and apply power there. You'd need a 12v source to do that though.

Looking at this underhood fuse box diagram, it appears there are three different relays for the fans. #1 is for the primary fan. #3 is for the secondary fan. #2 is the Cooling Fan Control Relay. You'll probably want to check the fuse marked "FAN CONT #1" (now that I'm looking closer).

[image]

If you want to pull the relay and apply power directly, you'd need to do the following:

[image]

This is the relay. Where pins #30 (power into relay - bottom right pin in picture) & #87 (out to fan - upper left pin in picture) connect into the socket, you'd need to take a jumper wire and jump this connection directly. Ensure the ignition is in the "On" position when you do this or you'll not get any results at all. As soon as you test to ensure there is power and the fan is working, pull the jumper. You don't need to drain your battery or cause other issues.